# How to extract tag content multiple times?

Tags: java

I've got a code which treat String as a one tag and extract everything together. In this case: **"abc</a> <a>def"**. How to extract from tags separatedly to obtain two Strings: "abc" and "def"?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Ex.findInTags("<a>((.*))</a>", "<a>abc</a> <a>def</a>");
}
public static void findInTags(String a, String b) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(a);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(b);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not VotingToClose only because I have some doubts, but possibly a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/598289

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Regex to parse XML/HTML because these **are not regular ranguages** so **regular expressions** cannot be used. Use dedicated tools like `XPath` (for XML) or `Jsoup` (HTML)

`Jsoup.parse("<a>abc</a> <a>def</a>").select("a")`

will give you all `a` elements and u can iterate over it and get required text from each node.